# Http bad request in REST WebApi

Tags: rest, http, asp.net-web-api, http-error

What Http error would you return if you have user who entered too long user name?
For example, limit is 150 characters and I want to validate that on server side, too. I'm building REST WebApi and I've know that if you are building REST everything should be in HTTP manner, as well as errors we return to the end user.
I've red that it's not good practices to return 400 Error. I would like to add some custom message as well, something that is understandable to user, like: "Username too long." 
Which Http error can I return to user if he exceeded the user name length limit? (lets imagine that right now we don't have client validation).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is

400 Bad Request - The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

You can return also "406 Not Acceptable" or "413 Request Entity Too Large".

You must put a custom message to return to the user the problem.

Note: You can see all http codes and usages in this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes